# Eclipse XUL : Contents not getting updated even after editing sourcecode

Tags: eclipse, xul, xulrunner

I am using xul in eclipse
When I create a xul file first time, it works correctly;
but if i change contents of source file the changes are not getting reflected in output.
If I run the xul file it gives the same output as earlier, the changes are not being reflected.

Comment: You need to configure which ever XUL IDE you are using with ECLIPSE. It may take effect if you restart FF browser.

Answer (score 1):

It is probably getting cached.

Try playing around with the following options in `about:config` or in [prefs.js](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Getting_started_with_XULRunner#Step_6%3a_Set_up_preferences):

- `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_fastload` (try `true`)
- `nglayout.debug.disable_xul_cache` (try `true`)
- `browser.cache.disk.enable` (try `false`)

also try starting Firefox/XULRunner with the commandline-option `-purgecaches`

[Setting up an extension development environment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Setting_up_extension_development_environment) explains these options in more detail.

You should just change these options for development purposes...

Comment: I am unable to find pref.js of about:config in my project (in eclipse)